# Extracting regression tree models built with R rpart

Tags: perl, r, regression, rpart

I've built several regression tree models using the `rpart` package in R and I need to migrate them into another language such as Perl.

The predict function works fine within R, but is there a way to print out something like the weighted formula at each node?

Comment: Everything is possible, but I'm not sure you'll find a function already written that perfectly suits your needs. If you read `?rpart.object` you can see for yourself how the tree is stored and write something to extract the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do can be done using a little hack of the Rattle package/GUI. If you install Rattle then from the command line use the `asRules()` function on your rpart fit object and you will get back a human readable rules set. I have used these rules to quickly convert to SQL or other languages in seconds. I hope this helps.